# AssertJ: how apply a comparison to any possible values without Condition

Tags: java, assertj

Just curious if is possible through `AssertJ` do something like this:

```
assertThat(somePojo).isNotNull()
                    .extracting("someproperty")
                    .doesNotContainNull()
                    .contains(any("a", "b"))

assertThat(somePojo).isNotNull()
                    .extracting("othersomeproperty")
                    .doesNotContainNull()
                    .contains(any(77, 88))
```

The *any* is a term or representation about the method that I need to use to check if the property value has *any* of the values provided, the `someproperty` for the case one could be either `a` or `b`, same thought for the second case but according with `77` or `88`

The type to evaluate should be any, `String`, `Integer` etc..

If I use [`anyOf`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#anyOf-org.assertj.core.api.Condition...-) method seems the unique way is through `Condition<T>` according with:

- [UsingConditionExamples.java](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/condition/UsingConditionExamples.java)
- [Extending assertions with conditions](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-conditions.html)

Not sure (I did a do a research and not results) if is possible use other method and get the same `anyOf` behaviour but without `Condition<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`containsAnyOf`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsAnyOf-ELEMENT...-) which has been added in 3.9.0, note that extracting properties returns a list (of one element in your case since you are extracting only one property).

```
Iterable<String> abc = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

// assertions will pass
assertThat(abc).containsAnyOf("b")
               .containsAnyOf("b", "c")
               .containsAnyOf("a", "b", "c")
               .containsAnyOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
               .containsAnyOf("e", "f", "g", "b");
```

Alternatively, use [`isIn`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#isIn-java.lang.Iterable-) to check that the value under test is in a given set of values.